# Getting Scalatest method info via reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scalatest

I'd like to get some information about the tests in the classpath.  I'd like it to look something like:

```
class-name:method-name:test-string
```

For example:

```
MyTestClass:{some anonymous class/method}:A Stack should pop values in last-in-first-out order
```

I can interrogate the `FlatSpec` easily enough to get the names and descriptions, but not the methods themselves.  If I use reflection, I can find the methods, but I don't know what they do because of the anonymous names.

Does anyone know how this might be done?